Compositing Disappears in the final render Animation
Im new to Blender and I recently got the Issue that my Compositing won´t be rendered in the final render Animation when I add it to the Video editor. It will render in the compositor (is that the name of it ? I guess) but not in the Final Render.
I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me
Thanks - Jones

Sorry, but I forgot my crystal ball. Would you mind helping me out by at least showing a screenshot of how you have set up your Compositor? Maybe this is a good start for finding a solution.
